# reverse tab goes out of popup window in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included given code in my html file

```
<input type="text" name="test-start" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" name="rest-start" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" name="best-start" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" name="nest-start" tabindex="4">
<input type="text" name="guest-start" tabindex="5">
```

when do tab then tabindex move in forward direction from 1-5 but when I do shift+tab then after tabindex1 it goes out of popup window and then go to url box and it moves there I wnat when my tabindex go to tabindex1 then do not move outside the popup box it will remain there only. I have tried given code also but after tabindex0 it goes out of the popup

```
<input type="text" name="test-start" tabindex="0">
<input type="text" name="rest-start" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" name="best-start" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" name="nest-start" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" name="guest-start" tabindex="4">
```

Please guide me how to solve this with the help of jquery. Is this possible or not.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. The browser UI will control the tab behaviour, and being able to tab to the address bar is required behaviour for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Are you sure about this